# Semicolon usage: an independent clause?

Tags: semicolons

> There were extra hot dogs.  This is where I have a role to play; to help eat leftovers.

Comment: First, please phrase this as an actual question. Secondly, I'd much prefer an em dash: "This is where I have a role to play—to help eat leftovers.

Comment: Taking my cue from *To sleep, perchance to dream*, I think I might prefer a ***comma***. But it seems to me whereas a ***dash*** or ***colon*** are "valid", what follows a ***semicolon*** should normally be capable of standing as a sentence on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, semicolons should separate complete clauses, if a period is too strong of a separation; use it rarely (more rarely than I am; adverbial phrases are preferred).  Your sentence deserves a colon, since the final phrase is an example of your role to play; it might have been a list.

Comment: I appreciate your advice; it will help!

Comment: Ah, behold the driveby downvoter, a plague upon this site. My guess is that the vote reflects the fact that your answer is unsupported. Certainly, the first clause (about semicolons) is correct per many style manuals. I'd guess that the clause about colons isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The correct usage of a semicolon is to separate to related independent clauses.

> There were extra hot dogs. This is where I have a role to play; I help eat leftovers.

Or, if you still want to have a dependent clause at the end, use a colon instead.

> There were extra hot dogs. This is where I have a role to play: help eat leftovers.